# TestEntityManager not found in Spring Boot Kotlin Tutorial in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I thoroughly followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin) tutorial, step-by-step.

I get this error in IntelliJ idea.

[image]

It's probably an IDE quirk, since the tests are actually running just fine.

I'm using Java 11 and the following dependecies versions:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.32"
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

I can't find anything to get rid of this annoying red highlight.

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-213.6777.52, built on January 28, 2022

Comment: Please try the current version. Spring Boot 2.7+ support has been added recently.

Comment: Just updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-213.7172.25, built on March 15, 2022. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: It's the old version. Please use the current release: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. Version: 2022.2
Build: 222.3345.118
25 July 2022